# Error thrown by compiled expression

Tags: warning-messages, compile

The following code is a minimal model of an error I am getting. It returns the error `Compiled expression {{0,2},{2,0}} should be a machine-size real number.` and `Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 1; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.`. However the same code runs without error if I remove the line `s=1;`, which ostensibly is doing nothing.

Naturally, I don't understand what is going on. Any pointers appreciated. Running v13.1.0.0 on Mac OS X x86 (64-bit).

```
Module[{fmn},
 
 fmn = Compile[{{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
   
   Sum[
    Module[{s},
     
     s = 1;
     
     {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
     
     ]
    , {j, 1, 2}]
   
   ];
 
 ArrayFlatten@Table[fmn[m, n], {m, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 1}]
 
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First load the package so we can do `CompilePrint`

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
```

Simplifying your minimal model further we see that `Compile` does not like `Sum` with `s` as a symbol; `MainEvaluate` gets called.

```
f = Compile[
   {{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
   Sum[
    Module[
     {s},
     s = 1;
     {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
     ],
    {j, 1, 2}
    ]
   ];

f[1, 1]  (* {{0, 2}, {2, 0}} with error message *)
CompilePrint[f]
```

> ```
>   2 arguments
>   3 Integer registers
>   1 Real register
>   1 Tensor register
>   Underflow checking off
>   Overflow checking off
>   Integer overflow checking on
>   RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>   I0 = A1
>   I1 = A2
>   I2 = 1
>   T(I2)0 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
>   Result = R0
>
>   1   R0 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{m, n}, Sum[Module[{s}, s = 1; {{0, 1}, \
>   {1, 0}}], {j, 1, 2}]][ I0, I1]]
>   2   Return
> ```

If we initialise `s=1` in the `Module` `Compile` is happier and can proceed with the `Sum`

```
g = Compile[
  {{m, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
  Sum[
   Module[
    {s = 1},
    {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
    ],
   {j, 1, 2}
   ]
  ]

g[1, 1] (* {{0, 2}, {2, 0}} *)
CompilePrint[g]
```

> ```
>   2 arguments
>   15 Integer registers
>   4 Tensor registers
>   Underflow checking off
>   Overflow checking off
>   Integer overflow checking on
>   RuntimeAttributes -> {}
>
>   I0 = A1
>   I1 = A2
>   I12 = 0
>   I14 = 2
>   I2 = 1
>   T(I2)0 = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}
>   Result = T(I2)3
>
>   1   T(I3)1 = {T(I2)0}
>   2   T(I2)3 = Part[ T(I3)1, I2]
>   3   I8 = Length[ T(I2)3]
>   4   T(I3)3 = {T(I2)0}
>   5   T(I2)1 = Part[ T(I3)3, I2]
>   6   T(I1)3 = Part[ T(I2)1, I2]
>   7   I10 = Length[ T(I1)3]
>   8   I3 = I12
>   9   T(I2)3 = Table[ I8, I10]
>   10  I6 = I12
>   11  goto 16
>   12  I9 = I12
>   13  goto 15
>   14  Element[ T(I2)3, I3] = I12
>   15  if[ ++ I9 <= I10] goto 14
>   16  if[ ++ I6 <= I8] goto 12
>   17  I4 = I14
>   18  I5 = I12
>   19  goto 22
>   20  T(I2)1 = T(I2)3 + T(I2)0
>   21  T(I2)3 = CopyTensor[ T(I2)1]]
>   22  if[ ++ I5 <= I4] goto 20
>   23  Return
> ```

Comment: Thank you for unpicking this. I see that initialising ``s`` with a value fixed the error. Is that a general principle? Should one always avoid uninitialised variables in compiled code? Is it because the type of ``s`` was unclear to the compiler?

Comment: I think that is generally a good idea.

Comment: In this particular instance, I suspect it's because of `Sum` which typically expects a function as the first argument.  eg `foo = Compile[{{m, _Integer}}, 
  Table[Module[{s}, s = 1; {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}], {j, 1, 2}]]` has no errors